# Method to copy primes from one array to another in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, primes

I'm rather new to Java, and I'm trying to figure out a way to copy all primes inside of an array and copy those to another array.

To do so, I've implemented a separate `isPrime()` method to check whether the element is a prime, and another method that counts the number of primes in that array `countPrimes()`, such that I can determine the new array's size.

Here is where I'm kind of stuck:

```
public static int[] primesIn(int[] arr) {
    int primeHolder = countPrimes(arr);
    int[] copyArr = new int[primeHolder];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (isPrime(arr[i]) == true) {
            copyArr[>Needs to start from 0<] = arr[i];
        }
    }
    return copyArr;
}

int[] arrayMan = {3,5,10,15,13};
```

At `copyArr` the position should be `0`, followed by `+1` everytime it finds a prime. If I were to give it `i` position, as in `copyArr[i] = arr[i]`, then say the prime is at position `5`, it would try to save the prime onto position `5`of `copyArr`, which doesn't exist if there are only three primes in the original array, which would've given `copyArr` a length of only three.

Something tells me a different for loop, or maybe even an additional one would help, but I can't see how I should implement it. Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a second index variable `int primeCount`, and increment it whenever you find a prime. No need for a 2nd loop.

In modern days of abundant memory, things are usually not done like this. If you don't have some extra hard requirements, you could just use a resizable [`ArrayList<Integer>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), and `add()` stuff in there. (and convert it back to int[] at the end if needed). This is also better in this case, because typically your `countPrimes` call will run much slower than ArrayList reallocations.

Answer (score 1):

Read your words carefully:

> At `copyArr` the position should be `0`, followed by `+1` **everytime it
>   finds a prime.**

That means that index in a new array does not depend on its position in the old array.
 Create a counter. And each time you place a prime number into a new array, increment it by 1. Thus you can always know where to put a new number.